# Changing the values on the x and y axis of a graph in Python

Tags: python, numpy, graph

if I had something like;

```
import numpy as np, math as m, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def test():
    x = [1,2,3]
    y = [m.log(0.1),m.log(0.2),m.log(0.3)]

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

This will display a graph with the y axis showing negative numbers. I was wondering how you make the graph display it as a logarithm instead (like what the list y was initially defined to be).

Thanks!

Comment: its np.log not m.log

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1183415/2286754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the log of a fraction is negative, by the definition of a log. For example 10^x=1/2, x *must* be negative to get a fractional value. That is the idea behind a log.  So your best bet is to display with a log scale so that it displays positive fractions.

<s>The easiest way to do this would be to take `10^x` where x is the decimal value, of every y value. Then you will have the y output as decimals, instead of negative numbers.</s>

Then you can set `.ylabel()` as "log scale".

**Edit:** I think what you are looking for is answered [on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points) about making custom ticks. You should be able to use `yticks` instead of `xticks` used in the answer.

Comment: Yes I understand that the values will be negative. I'm more referring to just making the labels in terms of ln(...) rather then as -ve numbers for aesthetics/preference more than anything.