# Pyplot rotated labels offset by one

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph

Just getting into matplot lib and running into odd problem - I'm trying to plot 10 items, and use their names on the x-axis. I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points) and it worked great, except that my label names are long and they were all scrunched up. So I found that you can rotate labels, and got the following:

```
plt.plot([x for x in range(len(df.columns))], df[df.columns[0]], 'ro',)
plt.xticks(range(10), df.columns, rotation=45)
```

[image: bad plot]

The labels all seem to be off by a tick ("Arthrobacter" should be aligned with 0). So I thought my indexing was wrong, and tried a bunch of other crap to fix it, but it turns out it's just odd (at least to me) behavior of the rotation. If I do `rotation='vertical'`, I get what I want:
[image]

I see now that the center of the labels are clearly aligned with the ticks, but I expected that they'd terminate on the ticks. Like this (done in photoshop):
[image: d]

Is there a way to get this done automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels are not "off", labels are actually placed via their "center". In your second image, the corresponding tick is above the center of the label, not above its endpoint. You can change that by adding `ha='right'` which modifies the horizontal alignement of the label.

```
plt.plot([x for x in range(len(df.columns))], df[df.columns[0]], 'ro',)
plt.xticks(range(10), df.columns, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

See the comparison below :

1)

```
plt.plot(np.arange(4), np.arange(4))
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), ['veryverylongname']*4, rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: i1]

2)

```
plt.plot(np.arange(4), np.arange(4))
plt.xticks(np.arange(4), ['veryverylongname']*4, rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, the `ha` parameter is what I was looking for, thanks!