# How can I map the values in an array to the bar labels in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda

I am new at Data Visualization with Python. I want to be able to plot the Groupby() results in a bar chart. I have converted a categorical array using the pd.factorize() function in Python. Then, I created a plot using the results of the groupby function.

Here is my code:

`fact=pd.factorize(data['DayOfWeek'])`

```
data['fact'].groupby(data['fact_dow']).count().plot(kind='bar',figsize=(14,8))
```

`plt.show()`

The resulting image is:
[image]

It looks almost good but the x-labels are the factorized results, I need to map them to their corresponding values.

Any one knows how to do this in a pythonic way? Also, if there are other suggestions as to how to do it, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the `data['DayOfWeek']` corresponds to the labels, then use `plt.xticks(data['DayOfWeek'])`

Comment: Thanks, the `xticks` change the values, however, how can I use String values in the Ticker? The ticker labels are held in the `fact[1]` array not in the `data` array

Comment: @JuanDaza It's still unclear to me. You are saying "how can I use String values in the Ticker?". what does that mean? how are you going to use it ? are you going to use it for something other than setting the x-ticks?

Comment: I figured it out, I am sorry if I was unclear. I wanted to add custom values to the x-ticker. These were not numerical values. I found it here [link](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points)