# Python matplotlib x-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to make a graph to display some data, my issue is I want the x-axis to have years value

```
df6=df6["percent"]
list = df6.values.tolist()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(list)
plt.show()
```

I get the graph 
￼

[image: Graph I have]

But I want the graph to be like this 
[image: Graph I want]

Please Help!

Comment: I think, this link will give you a hint on a way to do what you would like to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what your data looks like, but if you loop through your years data and add the value of 1880 to it all, your graph should display the x-axis similarly to the picture you have provided.

For example:

```
0 + 1880 = 1880
50 + 1880 = 1930
100 + 1880 = 1980
```

And so on..