# matplotlib adding string to a an axis

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
ydata = [55,60,65,70,75,80] 
xdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)  
set(plt.gca,'XTickLabel',{'Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June'}) 
plt.show()
```

I am using matplotlib and trying to add text values to appear on the x axis.

I have tried to use the following code but get the following error message
set(plt.gca,'XTickLabel',
{'Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June'}) 
TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 3  I am not sure what this 
is referring get current access I have set the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot with custom text for x axis points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`Sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)** are a Python data structure, it has nothing to do with what you want here, you only need to use **[`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xticklabels)** and **[`ax.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html)** to ensure all of them show in the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ydata = [55,60,65,70,75,80] 
xdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ax.set_xticks(xdata)
ax.set_xticklabels(['Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June'])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @daaxeman I'm glad to help! Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this how do "I accept" the answer

Comment: It's explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), you just need to click on the check mark beside it.

Comment: I think I have done it I have not used this before so sorry was not aware of the protocols