# How to plot two plots with strings as x axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot two figures in one image using matplotlib. Data which I want to plot is:

```
x1 = ['sale','pseudo','test_mode']
y1 = [2374064, 515, 13]

x2 = ['ready','void']
y2 = [2373078, 1514]
```

I want to plot the bar plot for both the figure in one image. I used the code given below:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax1.set_title('Two plots')
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
```

but its giving error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: PSEUDO
```

How I can plot them in one image using matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x1 = ['sale','pseudo','test_mode']
y1 = [23, 51, 13]

x2 = ['ready','void']
y2 = [78, 1514]

y = y1+y2
x = x1+x2
pos = np.arange(len(y))
plt.bar(pos,y)
ticks = plt.xticks(pos, x)
```

Separate figures in one image:

```
x1 = ['sale','pseudo','test_mode']
y1 = [23, 51, 13]

x2 = ['ready','void']
y2 = [78, 1514]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

pos1 = np.arange(len(y1))
ax1.bar(pos1,y1)
plt.sca(ax1)
plt.xticks(pos1,x1)

pos2 = np.arange(len(y2))
ax2.bar(pos,y2)
plt.sca(ax2)
plt.xticks(pos2,x2)
```

Comment: I can't draw like this. x1 and x2 are two different attributes. From your solution it will get plot as a one attribute. I want to make to separate figures for x1 and x2. Separate figure in one image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `x` values are not numbers, but text. Instead, plot the `y` values and then change the name of the xticks (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = ['sale','pseudo','test_mode']
y1 = [23, 51, 13]

x2 = ['ready','void']
y2 = [78, 1514]

f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
for (x, y, ax) in zip((x1, x2), (y1, y2), axes):
    ax.plot(y)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(x))) # make sure there is only 1 tick per value
    ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image: line graph]

For a bar graph, switch out `ax.plot(y)` with `ax.bar(range(len(x)), y)`. This will produce the following:

[image: bar graph]

Comment: It's giving error AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'

Comment: @neha I was in a hurry, and did not have time to verify the code. I've updated the example.

Comment: Did you know how I can plot the bar plot of this two diagrams?

Comment: @neha I added a bar graph as well. Consider accepting this answer if it solves your problem.