# matplotlib plot values not in order

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm encountering some matplotlib behaviour that I do not understand.
I have a daframe:

```
august.head()     
                     value
 config name    
low max velocity    -0.000145
medium max velocity -0.000165
reference           -0.000198
high max velocity   -0.000192
```

When I plot this dataframe using

```
plt.plot(august)
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

My data seems plotted chaotically and the blue line 'comes back to a previous x value' (sorry, that's the best I can do for a description of my problem)

I would like to see my data plotted with plt.plot(august) just as when I plot it using

```
august.plot()
```

Which gives me a good, ordered graph:
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you are using matplotlib 2.1. Is it an option to update matplotlib to 2.2.2?

Comment: Why don't you sort the dataframe values before you plot them?

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the config names were ordered alphabetically ?
In that case you could associate an integer to each config name, like here:
[plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points)