# My seaborn and Matplotlib plots look the same?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

lately people have been telling me that seaborn is the best data visualization package in Python, so I decided to try it out.  However, my plots look exactly identical to my matplotlib plots..

I am using PyCharm, Python 3.6.

Here is my super simple code to test the two:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

sns.lineplot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

and they both look like:

[image]

Normally, seaborn plots should have at leasthave a gridded blue background.  Why is mines not working?

Comment: Use Import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

Comment: ahh thanks that did the trick, so there is no way to have the choice of picking between matplotlib and seaborn?  Because the moment seaborn is set, all plots become that style.  Either way, thanks!

Comment: do `seaborn.set()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn is an extention to matplotlib, which simplifies certain tasks. I.e. often creating a plot with seaborn takes only 30 to 50% of the number of code lines it would take to plot with matplotlib directly. But every seaborn plot necessarily is a matplotlib plot.

Concerning the style, seaborn has some shortcuts on setting style parameters. Those are explained in detail in the [Aestetics tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html).

In short, you can use

```
seaborn.set()
```

to get the "darkgrid" theme; you can use

```
seaborn.reset_defaults()
```

to reset the parameters back to the matplotlib defaults.

Essentially[*] the same can be achieved with matplotlib via

```
plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")
```

and

```
plt.style.use("default")
```

For this read the [matplotlib customizing tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html).

---

[*] There are small differences, because `seaborn.set` also sets other parameters like defaults of figure size etc.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am a little too late for your answer but try using:

```
seaborn.set()
```