# How does the Seaborn timeseries plot with error bands example get its error band data from?

Tags: python, seaborn

This question relates to this [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html) from the Seaborn documentation.

I do not understand how the plotting library is obtaining error information.

The function called, with arguments is as follows.

```
lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="region", style="event", data=fmri)
```

If I understand correctly:

- The pandas dataframe containing the data is set with the `data` argument
- The name of the column containing x values is set using the `x` argument
- The name of the column containing y values is set using the `y` argument
- There are 4 lines plotted, the color and style for each line is set using the data in the columns defined by the names provided to the `hue` and `style` arguments
- There is no argument for the width of the error band (uncertainty data)

Have I misunderstood something? Where does the error width data come from? How does Seaborn know what widths to use when plotting the shaded regions?

[image: Seaborn Line Example]

Answer (score 2):

So seaborn creates errorbars based on the `errrobar` parameter.

For lineplot it is `errorbar=('ci', 95)` by default. If you don't want it to be visible, you can set the parameter to `None`.

For this example `errorbar=('ci', 95)`, means that the error bars are created using a 95% confidence interval.

The fluctuating error bars are created using a statistical method of [bootstrapping with replacements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). Essentially from what I understand, for each line, you take many samples with replacements and replot the line to get a distribution of lines. Then you take the 95% band using that distribution to get the error bands.

Hopefully, this explanation makes a little sense.

Also, read the documentation for [Seaborn: statistical estimation and errorbars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html?highlight=errorbar) and a tutorial [script](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/doc/_tutorial/error_bars.ipynb).

Comment: That makes sense to me and I'm familiar with the technique. I don't currently have any error bar regions on my figures, but that is probably not surprising as I only have one datapoint for each value of x. Hence, no bootstrapping.

Comment: This is not exactly the same question, but do you know how I can pass numerical data to Seaborn to use as the error band width?

Comment: I think it can be done, but it has limited capability. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203420/how-to-use-custom-error-bar-in-seaborn-lineplot) and also the custom example [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html?highlight=errorbar)