# Seaborn/Matplotlib create custom error band along line

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, average

I have an experiment with 10 participants and 96 accuracies collected for each. `acc_i` represents the participant's overall accuracy at timestep i. Therefore, I have a 10x96 numpy matrix which looks like this:

```
[[acc_0,acc_1,acc_2,...acc_95]
 [acc_0,acc_1,acc_2,...acc_95]
 [acc_0,acc_1,acc_2,...acc_95]
            .
            .
            .
 [acc_0,acc_1,acc_2,...acc_95]]
```

I want to plot a line of the average accuracy among all participants at each timestep, along with an error band that shows the average +- 1 standard deviation. I can calculate the average and standard deviations separately using `pd.Series(np.average(human_accuracies, axis=0))` and `pd.Series(np.std(human_accuracies, axis=0))`. However, this gives me two separate lines on a graph when I use:

```
sns.lineplot(data=avg_accuracies)
sns.lineplot(data=sd_accuracies)
```

This is shown below:

[image]

How can I make my plot into something more like what is shown here:

[image]

I'd like the error band to be calculated using the standard deviation at each time step `i` +- the average accuracy at each time step `i`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368485/draw-error-shading-bands-on-line-plot-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plt.fill_between` like this:

```
plt.fill_between(x=np.arange(len(avg_accuracies)),
                 y1=avg_accuracies - sd_accuracies,
                 y2=avg_accuracies + sd_accuracies,
                 alpha=0.25
                 )
plt.plot(np.arange(len(avg_accuracies)), avg_accuracies)
```

Output:

[image]