# How to turn x-axis values into a legend for matplotlib bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, legend

I am creating bar graphs for data that comes from series. However the names (x-axis values) are extremely long. If they are rotated 90 degrees it is impossible to read the entire name and get a good image of the graph. 45 degrees is not much better. I am looking for a way to label the x-axis by numbers 1-15 and then have a legend listing the names that correspond to each number.

This is the completed function I have so far, including creating the series from a larger dataframe

```
def graph_average_expressions(TAD_matches, CAGE): 
"""graphs the top 15 expression levels of each lncRNA"""

for i, row in TAD_matches.iterrows():
    mask = (
        CAGE['short_description'].isin(row['peak_ID'])
    )#finds expression level for peaks in an lncRNA
    average = CAGE[mask].iloc[:,8:].mean(axis=0).astype('float32').sort_values().tail(n=15)
    #made a new df of the top 15 highest expression levels for all averaged groups 
    #a group is peaks belong to the same lncRNA
    cell_type = list(average.index)
    expression = list(average.values)
    average_df = pd.DataFrame(
        list(zip(cell_type, expression)), 
        columns=['cell_type','expression']
    )
    colors = sns.color_palette(
        'husl', 
        n_colors=len(cell_type)
    )
    p = sns.barplot(
        x=average_df.index, 
        y='expression', 
        data=average_df, 
        palette=colors
    )
    cmap = dict(zip(average_df.cell_type, colors))
    patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]
    plt.legend(
        handles=patches, 
        bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), 
        loc='center left', 
        borderaxespad=0
    )
    plt.title('expression_levels_of_lncRNA_' + row['lncRNA_name'])
    plt.xlabel('cell_type')
    plt.ylabel('expression')
    plt.show()
```

Here is an example of the data I am graphing

```
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor2.CNhs13532         1.583428
Neutrophils_donor3.CNhs11905                                              1.832527
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Trehalose_dimycolate_TDM_donor2.CNhs13483     1.858384
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor1.CNhs13473                      1.873013
CD14_Monocytes_donor2.CNhs11954                                           2.041607
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor2.CNhs13488                      2.112112
CD14_Monocytes_donor3.CNhs11997                                           2.195365
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor1.CNhs13469         2.974203
Eosinophils_donor3.CNhs12549                                              3.566822
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_lipopolysaccharide_donor1.CNhs13470           3.685389
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Salmonella_donor1.CNhs13471                   4.409062
CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor3.CNhs13494                      5.546789
CD14_monocytes_-_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor3.CNhs13492       5.673991
Neutrophils_donor1.CNhs10862                                              8.352045
Neutrophils_donor2.CNhs11959                                             11.595509
```

With the new code above this is the graph I get, but no legend or title.
[image: This is my graph]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plot with custom text for x axis points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100985/plot-with-custom-text-for-x-axis-points)

Comment: Not really. The part I am having the most trouble with is making the legend reference whatever names are assigned to the xticks. Every time I try to make a legend it only lists the first xtick

Comment: Often, browsing through the Matplolib examples page you can find a feature you are looking for and see how it is done - [Table Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/table_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-table-demo-py)

Comment: Or add the info as text: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-autowrap-py

Comment: I haven't found an example of what I am trying to do. It may not be possible. The table is listing the values associated with each xtick, and I am only trying to list the names of each tick in a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setup the dataframe

1. verify the index of the dataframe to be plotted is reset, so it's integers beginning at 0, and use the index as the x-axis
2. plot the values on the y-axis

### Option 1A: Seaborn `hue`

- The easiest way is probably to use `seaborn.barplot` and use the `hue` parameter with the `'names'`
- [Seaborn: Choosing color palettes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

  - This plot is using `husl`
  - Additional options for the `husl` palette can be found  at [`seaborn.husl_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.husl_palette.html#seaborn.husl_palette)
- The bars will not be centered for this option, because they are placed according to the number of hue levels, and there are 15 levels in this case.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# plt styling parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

# create a color palette the length of the dataframe
colors = sns.color_palette('husl', n_colors=len(df))

# plot
p = sns.barplot(x=df.index, y='values', data=df, hue='names')

# place the legend to the right of the plot
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

### Option 1B: Seaborn `palette`

- Using the `palette` parameter instead of `hue`, places the bars directly over the ticks.
- This option requires "manually" associating `'names'` with the colors and creating the legend.

  - [`patches`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) uses `Patch` to create each item in the legend. (e.g. the rectangle, associated with color and name).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

# create a color palette the length of the dataframe
colors = sns.color_palette('husl', n_colors=len(df))

# plot
p = sns.barplot(x=df.index, y='values', data=df, palette=colors)

# create color map with colors and df.names
cmap = dict(zip(df.names, colors))

# create the rectangles for the legend
patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]

# add the legend
plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

### Option 2: [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- This option also requires "manually" associating `'names'` with the palette and creating the legend using `Patch`.
- [Choosing Colormaps in Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#choosing-colormaps-in-matplotlib)

  - This plot is using `tab20c`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

# plt styling parameters
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

# chose a color map with enough colors for the number of bars
colors = [plt.cm.tab20c(np.arange(len(df)))]

# plot the dataframe
df.plot.bar(color=colors)

# create color map with colors and df.names
cmap = dict(zip(df.names, colors[0]))

# create the rectangles for the legend
patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]

# add the legend
plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0)
```

[image]

### Reproducible DataFrame

```py
data = {'names': ['CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor2.CNhs13532', 'Neutrophils_donor3.CNhs11905', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Trehalose_dimycolate_TDM_donor2.CNhs13483', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor1.CNhs13473', 'CD14_Monocytes_donor2.CNhs11954', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor2.CNhs13488', 'CD14_Monocytes_donor3.CNhs11997', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor1.CNhs13469', 'Eosinophils_donor3.CNhs12549', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_lipopolysaccharide_donor1.CNhs13470', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Salmonella_donor1.CNhs13471', 'CD14_monocytes_treated_with_Candida_donor3.CNhs13494', 'CD14_monocytes_-_treated_with_Group_A_streptococci_donor3.CNhs13492', 'Neutrophils_donor1.CNhs10862', 'Neutrophils_donor2.CNhs11959'],
        'values': [1.583428, 1.832527, 1.858384, 1.873013, 2.041607, 2.1121112, 2.195365, 2.974203, 3.566822, 3.685389, 4.409062, 5.546789, 5.673991, 8.352045, 11.595509]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a different route. Made a string *mapping* x values to the names and added it to the figure.

Made my own DataFrame for illustration.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import string,random
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':[''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters,15))
                           for _ in range(10)],
                   'data':[random.randint(1,20) for _ in range(10)]})
```

Make the plot.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.index,df.data)
```

Make the *legend*.

```
x_legend = '\n'.join(f'{n} - {name}' for n,name in zip(df.index,df['name']))
```

Add the *legend* as a Text artist and adjust the plot to accommodate it.

```
t = ax.text(.7,.2,x_legend,transform=ax.figure.transFigure)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=.65)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

---

That can be made *dynamic* by getting and using the Text artist's size and the Figure's size.

```
# using imports and DataFrame from above
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

ax.bar(df.index,df.data)
x_legend = '\n'.join(f'{n} - {name}' for n,name in zip(df.index,df['name']))
t = ax.text(0,.1,x_legend,transform=ax.figure.transFigure)

# find the width of the Text and place it on the right side of the Figure
twidth = t.get_window_extent(renderer=r).width
*_,fwidth,fheight = fig.bbox.extents
tx,ty = t.get_position()
tx =  .95 - (twidth/fwidth)
t.set_position((tx,ty))

# adjust the right edge of the plot/Axes
ax_right = tx - .05
fig.subplots_adjust(right=ax_right)
```